# Delete files using a Windows command and display the list of deleted files

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, del

I want to delete files from a folder with pattern. I am using a C# program which calls a Windows command and prints the log of the command. Currently I am using this command:

```
del Test\*xyz* /s
```

Using /s switch, I get the list of files which are deleted in the log. But /s switch also deletes the files from the subdirectory which I don't want. Is there a way to delete files and get list of files?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correct, you want to delete files within a folder (without files in subdirectories). You can achieve this by using a [for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)-loop within a Batch-File.

For your use case you would write something like the following into a batch (`.bat`) file:

```
@ECHO OFF

for /f %%i in ('dir Test\*xyz* /b /a-d') do (
  echo %%i
  del %%i
)
```

The loop iterates through every line in the result of the `dir` command and prints the name of the file into the console. Afterwards it gets deleted.

As the documentation of the [for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)-loop states:

> - Iterating and file parsing
>
>   Use file parsing to process command output, strings, and file content. Use iterative variables to define the content or strings that you want to examine, and use the various *ParsingKeywords* options to further modify the parsing. Use the *ParsingKeywords* token option to specify which tokens should be passed as iterative variables. **Note that when used without the token option, /f will only examine the first token**.
>
>   File parsing consists of reading the output, string, or file content, and then breaking it into individual lines of text and parsing each line into zero or more tokens. The for loop is then called with the iterative variable value set to the token. By default, /f passes the first blank separated token from each line of each file. Blank lines are skipped.
>
>   The syntaxes are:
>
>   ```
>   for /f ["<ParsingKeywords>"] {%%|%}<Variable> in (<Set>) do <Command> [<CommandLineOptions>]
>   for /f ["ParsingKeywords"] {%%|%}<Variable> in ("<LiteralString>") do <Command> [<CommandLineOptions>]
>   for /f ["<ParsingKeywords>"] {%%|%}<Variable> in ('<Command>') do <Command> [<CommandLineOptions>]
>   ```

So in the above example we used the last version (used output from a command).
The specified command is the [dir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir) command.

As the documentation of the [dir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir) command states:

> **`/b`** Displays a bare list of directories and files, with no additional information. /b overrides /w.

and

> **`/a[[:]<Attributes>]`** Displays only the names of those directories and files with the attributes that you specify. If you omit /a, dir displays the names of all files except hidden and system files. If you use /a without specifying Attributes, dir displays the names of all files, including hidden and system files.
>
> The following list describes each of the values that you can use for Attributes. Using a colon (:) is optional. Use any combination of these values, and do not separate the values with spaces.
>
> `d` Directories
>   `h` Hidden files
>   `s` System files
>   `l` Reparse points
>   `r` Read-only files
>   `a` Files ready for archiving
>   `i` Not content indexed files
>   `-` Prefix meaning "not"

so you would need to use `/b` for the bare list of filenames and `/a-d` to exclude possible directories in the result list.

**On a side note:** You can also achive these things using plain C#. If you need help, just let me know ;-)